# Issue with result set from stored procedure report generation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Visual studio based stored procedure that generates a report for a monthly audit process.  In the database being queried, all data for each month lives in its own individual table (Contacts_month_1, Contacts_month_2, etc.)

The SQL used in this report generation has some minor logic included, to allow it to work dynamically, rather than use hard coded dates.  The problem arose at the start of January 2017, when I started receiving not just the results for the prior month, but additionally the prior year as well.  To be specific, the audit report for December 2016 included data for both 12/2016 and 12/2015.  Initially I thought it was a fluke of some kind based on the turn of the year, and we have not had this automated process during the turn as of yet.  Unfortunately when I came in to the office today, inside the output file for January 2017, I also received the results for January 2016.

I attempted to include a year check to the process, however I am still getting the same result output.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
Declare @GetMonth TinyInt
,@SessionTable varchar(50)
,@ContactTable varchar(50)
,@TableVersion varchar(2)
Declare @GetYear SmallInt
,@SessionTable_year varchar(50)
,@ContactTable_year varchar(50)
,@TableVersion_year varchar(4)

Set @GetMonth=MONTH(cast(GetDate() as Datetime))-1 
Set @GetYear=YEAR(cast(GetDate() as Datetime))

If (@getmonth=0) Set @GetMonth=12 + (@GetYear-1)

Set @TableVersion=CAST(@getMonth as varchar(2)) 
Set @SessionTable='[CentralDWH].[dbo].[Sessions_month_' +@tableversion +']'
Set @ContactTable ='[CentralDWH].[dbo].[Contacts_month_' +@tableversion +']'

-- Select @GetMonth,@GetYear (DEBUGGING STATEMENT)
-- Select @SessionTable,@ContactTable (DEBUGGING STATEMENT)


Exec('SELECT [PBX_id] as AgentID 
            ,[p22_value] as Skill
            ,''Athens'' as Location
            ,Convert(varchar(20),c.[local_start_time],120) as local_start_time
            ,convert(varchar(20),c.[local_end_time],120) as local_end_time
            ,U.[USER_NAME] 
            ,call_id
      FROM '+@SessionTable +' S
           Inner join dbo.Users U on S.user_key=U.user_key 
           inner Join '+ @ContactTable+'  C on S.contact_key=C.contact_key
      Where is_screen > 0 
            And Unit_Num between 398003 and 398005 
            and P22_value is not null 
            and c.[local_start_time] > ' + @GetYear 
      + ' order by local_start_time')
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the `@GetMonth` variable is used for returning the previous month

```
Set @GetMonth = MONTH(CAST(GetDate() AS Datetime)) - 1
```

After a quick look after you procedure my first issue was this line of code:

```
IF (@getmonth = 0) 
   SET @GetMonth = 12 + (@GetYear - 1)
```

I don't understand why are you setting the `@GetMonth` variable to 12 + current year -1 and I assume this is the cause to the problem.

Did you want to get the 12th month of the previous year when the current month is 1 (January)? If yes then you can easily change the If block to

```
If @GetMonth = 0 
Begin
     Set @GetMonth = 12
     Set @GetYear = @GetYear - 1
End
```

Other issues:

- It's recommended to keep the consistency of the names of the variables `@GetMonth`, `@getmonth`, this will cause an error if the database collation is case sensitive.
- `@GetMonth` is declared as `TinyInt` and this will cause an arithmetic overflow if you try to store the year

I recommend testing the dynamic SQL statement that you are composing here with some hard coded values to check the results returned, you can use January and 2016 to check if the actual issue in your procedure or it's in your query.

Hope it helps

Comment: That was indeed my idea behind trying to specify the GetYear-1 change.  I am by no means a seasoned query writer, and I'm attempting to piecemeal all this together based off of knowledge I haven't attempted to exercise in the last 4 years.  The bigger confusing bit is if you remove all @GetYear references, it would still provide 2 years worth of data in the result set.

I will do some more digging on this, to see what I can pull off.  I appreciate the direction you have provided.

Comment: In that case i suggest checking your joins and your conditions in the WHERE clause , the issue must be there somewhere. Glad I could help and please let me know if you find the cause of it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, I figured out the root of the problem, and it was because i was not casting the GetYear as a varchar when trying to run the T-SQL statement.  This in turn caused the variable to be completely ignored.  I also cleaned up the query a little bit after realizing i was goofing up pretty hard.

Below is the cleaned up functional query, so that it may help someone in the future:

```
Declare @GetMonth SmallInt,
@SessionTable varchar(50),
@ContactTable varchar(50),
@TableVersion varchar(2),
@GetYear SmallInt,
@YearCheck varchar(4)

Set @GetMonth=MONTH(cast(GetDate() as Datetime))-1
Set @GetYear=YEAR(cast(GetDate() as Datetime))-1

If (@GetMonth=0) 
Begin
    Set @GetMonth =12
    Set @GetYear =@GetYear - 1
End

Set @TableVersion=CAST(@GetMonth as varchar(2))
Set @SessionTable='[CentralDWH].[dbo].[Sessions_month_' +@tableversion +']'
Set @ContactTable ='[CentralDWH].[dbo].[Contacts_month_' +@tableversion +']'
Set @YearCheck=CAST(@GetYear as varchar(4))

--Select @GetMonth,@GetYear,@YearCheck (DEBUGGING STATEMENT)
-- Select @SessionTable,@ContactTable (DEBUGGING STATEMENT)


Exec('SELECT 
[PBX_id] as AgentID,
[p22_value] as Skill,
''Athens'' as Location,
Convert(varchar(20),c.[local_start_time],120) as local_start_time,
convert(varchar(20),c.[local_end_time],120) as local_end_time,
U.[USER_NAME],
call_id



FROM '+@SessionTable +' S
Inner join dbo.Users U on S.user_key=U.user_key 
inner Join '+ @ContactTable+'  C on S.contact_key=C.contact_key

Where is_screen>0 
And  Unit_Num between 398003 and 398005 
And P22_value is not null 
And year(c.[local_start_time]) > '+@YearCheck+'
   order by local_start_time')
```

Once I cleaned all this up and remembered to cast the year properly, everything fell into place.